# Adding and updating data in R packages

Tags: r, r-package, rdata

I'm writing my own R package to carry out some specific analyses for which I make a bunch of API calls to get some data from some websites. I have multiple keys for each API and I want to cycle them for two reasons:

1. Ensure I don't go over my daily limit
2. Depending on who is using the package, different keys may be used

All my keys are stored in a .csv file `api_details.csv`. This file is read by a function that gets the latest usage statistics and returns the key with the most calls available. I can add the .csv file to the `package/data` folder and it is available when the package is loaded but this presents two problems:

1. The .csv file is not read properly and all columns names are pasted together to create a single variable name and all values pasted together to create a single observation per row.
2. As I continue working, I would like to add more keys (and perhaps more details about the keys) to the `api_details.csv` but I'm not sure about how to do that.

I can save the details as an `.RData` file but I'm not sure about how it would be updated or read outside of R (by other people). Using .csv means that anyone using the package can easily add/remove some keys.

What's the best method to address 1, 2 above?

Comment: Have you checked out Hadley Wickham's book 'R Packages: Organize, Test, Document, and Share Your Code'? You can read it at http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/ . Here's a section on handling data http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/data.html

Comment: Thanks @DavidRosenman, I read that but I'm not sure how to update the data with new keys etc. For my own use, I can easily go back to the package and make a few changes but others users trying to use my package won't be able to.